# Impromptu - possible to turn off the scrolling for a state?

Tags: jquery, impromptu

I'm using Impromptu to walk users through a web application.

Everything works well, except one thing.

One of the states, let's call it State 2, references a container in a "social media bar" at the bottom of the page.  This bar uses jquery to stay fixed at the bottom, even when the page scrolls.

Here's the problem:

State 1 works fine -> User Clicks "Next" -> State 2 starts -> Impromptu gets position of container on social media bar -> Impromptu scrolls the screen to bring container up higher -> Social media bar auto-adjusts to stay fixed ->  RESULT: Impromptu prompt is no longer pointing to the container

I know I can adjust the Y value on the state, but this value will vary.  I'd prefer if I could turn off scrolling for that state, so that the Impromptu doesn't scroll the screen before displaying the next prompt.

Is there anyway to turn off scrolling just for one state?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I bought the e-book on the Impromptu site.  It's nice, but doesn't help with this particular issue.

Comment: Is it possible to use CSS to fix the container rather than javascript?

Comment: I just checked with the developer of the bottom widget bar, and he said it is in fact fixed with CSS.  But, same problem.  Impromptu gets the current position, then scrolls, then opens, then the bar moves away.